# SSRS 2008 reexecute report when parameters changed

Tags: caching, reporting-services, parameters

I have a report with many parameters, some dropdown lists some textual and some dates.

After the report viewer is loaded, user choosed parameters and pressed the 'View Report' button the report is loaded perfect.

Now user wish to change on of the many parameters enterd and watch the report....
after pressing the 'View Report' button, he get the same data in each page number wich been watched before until he press the refresh button..... (Caching of pages i guess).

I changed the report Execution property to allways run the report from most recent data.

my temporarly solution was to add a 'New Report' button above the report in order to refrash page (in that case no page is being cached), the problem is old parameters are also being flushed what make the report user put all again when he just wanted to change 1!!!!!

any creative solution will be appreciated.

Noam.

**EDITED**

[image: Params]

Comment: Are there any params using expression's (and maybe connected to other param values)?

Comment: @niktrs most of the params are from a dataset some are plain text (wildcard search) and some are dates non are connected to each other

Comment: Are you creating snapshots on the RS server? Check report properties etc

Comment: @niktrs nope, i do use most of them in the query of the main dataset in the report not as a filter (i thought that might be the issue but it didnt solved the problem when i changed it)

Comment: Can you provide screenshots from report's properties for parameters and execution?

Comment: @niktrs cant add more then that

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately, I have no more good ideas, beside what gbn said about checking carefully the properties of the reportnon the report server

Comment: @niktrs another piece of information i call the reportviewr from other page using '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=....>'

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution apperently the application calling the window defind the window to cach the data. 
I had to change the server side configuration in order to solve this issue.

not a very halpfull post.... sorry